# How to automatically update property in MSVS2012 debugger?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I'm using MSVS2012 and I develop in C++ .NET. When debugging, I watch variables that are *property* 's of certain classes. When the property change I have to update the watches manually (because it implies calling get() to object instances) using the small "2-arrow icon" at the left of the watch boxes.

My question is: is it possible to set the debugger to enable it to automatically call the get() methods in order to refresh the displayed values? In other words, is it possible to see the property values as if they were simple variables?

**Note**: Maybe this applies to MSVS2010 too?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't automatically refresh the properties, and there is a reason for that....
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4ecfxd9.aspx 
Calling for propertie